# Angularjs How to pass parameter back to controller from directive with ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that handles the comments process.  I'm binding it to a parent Controller, as followings:

```
<div commentable signin="signIn()"</div>
```

In the comment template I have multiple signin provider buttons; therefore I need to pass the provider back to the parent Controller.  But doing this gives me undefined.

Here is the button in the directive:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="signin('app')">Sign In</button>
```

Here is the Controller function:

```
$scope.signIn = function (provider) {
     console.log('clicked signin ' + provider);         
}
```

How do can I bind the provider string from the ng-click to Ctrl's provider in the function?

Comment: Think you might be looking for "=" in your isolate scope for the directive like scope: {signIn:"="} so the function that's passed in is called... not sure though showing the directive may help.

Answer (score 2):

What you have should work.  Make sure `signIn()` is declared within your controller though.  As such:

```
 function YourController($scope) {  
     $scope.signIn = function (provider) {
        console.log('clicked signin ' + provider);         
 }}
```

Assuming your button lives in the controller as such:

```
 <div ng-controller="YourController">    
     <button type="button" ng-click="signIn('test')">Sign In</button>
 </div>
```

Here's a fiddle of this working:  http://jsfiddle.net/tAsgt/

Comment: it's weird.  I'm getting the following in the console: clicked signin undefined.  So the two are wired up, but for some reason the provider 'test' is not passing through from the button to the controller.

Comment: Actually it's showing in the console: clicked signin provider.  Hum.

Comment: Odd.  I just updated that fiddle so it has two buttons and the result of the click is shown next to "result:".  Have a look and see if the buttons work for you.

Comment: Yes the jsfiddle works.  However, remember I'm passing this through a directive first.  I think the issue resides in the directive where I'm  passing signin="signIn()".   BTW I had 'provider' in signin="signIn('provider')"; removing that, it's back to showing undefined again.

Comment: Could you mock up a fiddle showing how you have it set up?  With the directive?  Then we'll be sure we all are on the same page.