# How To Pass Template-Defined Variable to Angular Controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click

This question is a long overdue extension of [Angularjs How to pass parameter back to controller from directive with ng-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483842/angularjs-how-to-pass-parameter-back-to-controller-from-directive-with-ng-click) in which strings are able to be passed to an Angular controller, but variables defined in the template are not.

In this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bharwcb/9y5v3zgo/6/) 'string' is passed through to the controller, and var foo is 'undefined'.

index.html:

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="YourController">
    <button type="button" ng-click="showString(foo)">One</button>
    <button type="button" ng-click="showString('Two')">Two</button>
    <p>Result: {{string}}</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
    var foo = "bar";
</script>
```

main.js:

```
function YourController($scope) {
    $scope.string='';
  $scope.showString = function (provider) {
    $scope.string= provider;
  }
}
```

(First Stack Overflow post here.. go easy on me ;))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, here's the [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bharwcb/9y5v3zgo/9/).

1) In `index.html`, I changed

```
<script>
  var foo = "bar";
</script>
```

to

```
<script>
  window.foo = "bar";
</script>
```

2) In `main.js`, I added

```
$scope.foo = window.foo;
```

Feel free to comment if there are better solutions.